# Does freezing raw milk kills harmful bacteria present in the milk?

Tags: food-safety, milk, frozen, raw

I have been drinking shakes made from frozen raw milk; just wondering that could it lead to any illness.

Does freezing raw milk kills harmful bacteria present in the milk?

Comment: You have many misconceptions about milk.

Answer (score 9):

No, freezing in a normal home freezer [does not](https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/Does-freezing-food-kill-bacteria) kill bacteria. They typically just enter a dormant state and reactivate as soon as you thaw the milk. Freezing a safe food extends the storage life, but does not make an otherwise unsafe food safe.

Comment: The one exception to this I can think of is deep-freezing fish or meat to kill (certain kinds of) parasites. This doesn't apply to the OP's case, of course... different food, different bad bugs, and a home freezer can't get nearly cold enough for it.

Comment: @Sneftel - in the case of bacteria etc, colder won't help. They are routinely stored at -80 C or even liquid nitrogen (-196 C) in the lab. In fact, they are more stable at these lower temperatures than at -20 because of the ice crystal formation that goes on at -20